# Combine rows in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, function, plsql

[image: Sample Data]

I use PL/SQL to extract data. I'd like to know how I can combine these rows. As you can see, there are cells with no data, but in fact, the data is available in the next row.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: ok well, how do I use the html function to create a table?

Comment: Remove img and post the table sample as plain text.

Answer (score 0):

Skipping the way you asked the question, here is the solution (it may look complicated but it works):

```
SELECT postcode, 
       replace(REGEXP_REPLACE(replace(LISTAGG(moved_in, '-') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ROWNUM),'No Data Available',''),'([^-]*)(-\1)+($|-)', '\1\3'),'-','')     AS moved_in,
       replace(REGEXP_REPLACE(replace(LISTAGG(moved_out, '-') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ROWNUM),'No Data Available',''),'([^-]*)(-\1)+($|-)', '\1\3'),'-','')    AS moved_out,
       replace(REGEXP_REPLACE(replace(LISTAGG(district, '-') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ROWNUM),'No Data Available',''),'([^-]*)(-\1)+($|-)', '\1\3'),'-','')     AS district,
       replace(REGEXP_REPLACE(replace(LISTAGG(district_new, '-') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ROWNUM),'No Data Available',''),'([^-]*)(-\1)+($|-)', '\1\3'),'-','') AS district_new,
       replace(REGEXP_REPLACE(replace(LISTAGG(country_code, '-') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ROWNUM),'No Data Available',''),'([^-]*)(-\1)+($|-)', '\1\3'),'-','') AS country_code
FROM   test_tab
GROUP BY postcode;
```

Gives me output:

```
POSTCODE |  MOVED_IN |  MOVED_OUT | DISTRICT    | DISTRICT_NEW | COUNTRY_CODE
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
B23 6AD  |  16/11/04 |  16/11/04  | Birmingham  | Birmingham   | 00B23
```

I used this code to create test data:

```
CREATE TABLE test_tab
(Postcode VARCHAR2(100),
Moved_in DATE,
Moved_out DATE,
District VARCHAR2(100),
District_New VARCHAR2(100),
Country_code VARCHAR2(100));

INSERT INTO test_tab VALUES ( 'B23 6AD', sysdate, SYSDATE, 'No Data Available', 'No Data Available', '00B23');
INSERT INTO test_tab VALUES ('B23 6AD', sysdate, SYSDATE, 'Birmingham', 'Birmingham', '00B23');
INSERT INTO test_tab VALUES ('B23 6AD', SYSDATE, SYSDATE, 'Birmingham', 'Birmingham', 'No Data Available');
```

Comment: time consuming with 100k records.

Comment: Maybe you should use some indexes on your table or other optimization - you didn't provide any more details - anyway is this answer gives the wanted result?

Comment: No. Im looking for a method to merge rows. Some sort of a distinct function. What you show requires too much manual input.